PyQt5 QFileDialog QDialogButtonBox.Open.setText doesn't work properly
I think there is a bug in PyQt5 when handling QDialogButtonBox.Open in QFileDialog. If I change the button text, when I select a file in the list it recovers the original text.
With QDialogButtonBox.Cancel there is no problem.
Here is my code:
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QFileDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QApplication, QListView)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject)

class OpenFileDialog(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Path
        self.path = os.getcwd()

        options = self.Options()
        options = self.DontUseNativeDialog
        self.setOptions(options)

        # Ok and Cancel buttons
        d_button = self.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "buttonBox")
        d_button.setFixedWidth(110)
        self.but_ok = d_button.button(QDialogButtonBox.Open)
        self.but_ok.setText("Seleccionar")
        self.but_cancel = d_button.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.but_cancel.setText("Cancelar")

        self.but_ok.clicked.connect(self.click_ok_button)
        self.but_cancel.clicked.connect(self.click_cancel_button)

        # My solution
        fil_lst = self.findChild(QListView, "listView")
        fil_lst.clicked.connect((self.selectitem))

    def selectitem(self):
        self.but_ok.setText("Seleccionar")

    def click_ok_button(self):
        print("Select file")

    def click_cancel_button(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Select None")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = OpenFileDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I solved it by changing the text every time the list is clicked, but it is not a pretty solution.
Does anyone know a more pythonic solution?
I updated the code to remove the lines of the translation because it is not the object of the question, just a verification tool, and it causes confusion.
Actually, in the original project I make an adaptation of QFileDialog for another use in which the button performs selection functions. Obviously the code is a simplification to determine the problem.
As musicamante says, QFileDialog always updates the text of the "Accept" button according to the selected item, file or directory. That is, it works dynamically, not statically as I thought.
Therefore, I think the best solution is to incorporate a new button to QFileDialog that works as I want or program a specific dialog adapted to my needs.
Thank you very much for your help.
In the end I decided to replace the open button. In case it helps anyone, here is the final code:
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QFileDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QApplication, QStyle)

class OpenFileDialog(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Path
        self.path = os.getcwd()

        options = self.Options()
        options = self.DontUseNativeDialog
        self.setOptions(options)

        # Accept and Cancel buttons
        self.setLabelText(OpenFileDialog.Reject, "Cancelar")
        d_button = self.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "buttonBox")
        self.but_cancel = d_button.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

        # My solution
        d_button.removeButton(d_button.button(QDialogButtonBox.Open))
        self.but_accept = d_button.addButton("Seleccionar", QDialogButtonBox.AcceptRole)
        icon = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileIcon)
        self.but_accept.setIcon(icon)

        self.but_accept.clicked.connect(self.click_accept_button)
        self.but_cancel.clicked.connect(self.click_cancel_button)

    def click_accept_button(self):
        print("Select file")

    def click_cancel_button(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Select None")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = OpenFileDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



Using translation won't change anything, because what matters is the call to setText() (even if done internally). Note that your usage of translate() is inappropriate: the first argument is the context, the second is the string that has to be translated (besides, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to have a translation function if you have to provide the translated text). Also note that Qt normally ships with translations for the most common languages, if the system/setup is properly configured you shouldn't need to translate those buttons. Anyway, for this try ("QFileDialog", "&Open").

As stated in my previous (deleted) comment, QFileDialog always updates the text of the "ok" button. It considers the text used with setLabelText() as suggested by the current answer, but only if the selected item is of the type set by setFileMode() (eg. a file when not using Directory). If you always want the same text, your solution is relatively appropriate, programmatically speaking, but not considering UX aspects. There's a very good reason for which that text is changed if a directory is selected, and you must consider that.

As stated by ekhumoro comment on the same answer, and considering what written in my first comment, setLabelText() is not meant for translation. If you have issues with Qt translations, then that is your problem and you should address that, trying to change the label because the translation system doesn't work for you is completely inappropriate, especially if your program is intended for users of other languages, and also if you don't consider the implications of arbitrarily setting a button text that must have different values depending on the context.

Have you tried using setLabelText()?
class OpenFileDialog(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        ...

        self.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Accept, "Seleccionar")
        self.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Reject, "Cancelar")

        ...


Thank you for your help.
I used translation out of desperation, to try something, because I couldn't find any acceptable solution.
Hanstjua's solution works for bot, parent and child classes, if I select files but not if I open a directory, which repeats the problem.
However, I reiterate that the cancel button works without any problem with any of the solutions tested, also with Hanstjua's.

@ManuelAntón Why is opening a directory a problem? It would be wrong to show "select" for that, since you can only choose files. In directory file-mode, "select" is shown, since you can choose a directory. For all other QFileDialog text, you should use the built-in Qt translations. The setLabelText method is meant for customisation, not translating standard labels like "cancel".
